# Why isn't my delegated event handler firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following html button inside a script tag. The idea was to keep it from initially loading on the page without a slight flicker when the page reloads.

```
<script id="pagination" type="text/template">

    <input type = "submit" value = ">" id = "nextbutton" class = "scanbutton" style =  "width: 40px; height: 26px" />

</script>

<input type="submit" id="first" value="Clix">
<div id="paginationbuttons"></div>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
  $('#first').on('click', function() {
    var pageButtons= $('#pagination').html();
    $('#paginationbuttons').html(pageButtons);
    alert('good so far');

  });   

  $('#paginationbuttons').on('click', ':button', function () {
    alert('good again'); // No luck here
  });
```

I can extract the html from the script with the first click event but the next click event doesn't seem to get bound when js reads the page (no second alert running). Where's my problem? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zsv433kb/41/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `:button` selector to select an `input[type=submit]`. Change your selector to `:input` or change your tag to a `button` or `input[type=button]`.

Comment: Thanks. Not paying attention.

Comment: Using :button on an input is not necessarily a problem: http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/